# How do I get different colors for parts of string object property binded to label in ItemControl?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, viewmodel, richtext

This is my object type:

```
public class selectedLevel
{
   public string Level
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

   public string PlanetSelected
    {
        get; set;

    }
   public string houseDetails
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    
}
```

This is my itemTemplate:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="LevelDetails" Margin="-464,416,120,-484"   BorderBrush ="Black"  ItemsSource="{Binding selectedLevels}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
   <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col1" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col2" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col3" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col4" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col5" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col6" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col7" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col8" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col9" />
               <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Col10"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Row1"/>
               <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Row2"/>
               <RowDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Row3"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="LevelName" Grid.Row="0"  Content="{Binding Level}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="16" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="{x:Null}"/>
            <Label x:Name="PlanetName" Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding PlanetSelected}" FontSize="14" Foreground="Red" BorderBrush="Black" FontWeight="Bold" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" BorderThickness="1" />
            <Label x:Name="LevelDetails" Grid.Row="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Content="{Binding houseDetails}" FontSize="14" BorderBrush="Black" FontWeight="Bold" BorderThickness="1" />
         </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

The User control is bound with an object with an observable collection of type selectedLevel(shown at the top).

I am adding the properties of SelectedLevels in a view model as follows:

```
selectedLevels.Add(new selectedLevel
{
    Level = "Mahadasha",
    PlanetSelected = Mahadashas[0].rulerName,
    houseDetails =  indicesList[0]  +  ", " + indicesList[1] + ", " + indicesList[2]
                    
});
```

I am trying to get different colors for `indicesList[0]`, `indicesList[1]` and `indicesList[2]` in 3rd label which is bound with `houseDetails` but I can only change full text color and not a part of it.

I am totally lost here. Can I get some assistance on how to set different colors to parts of string?

Comment: You are already showing three properties with different Foreground. It seems straightforward to split houseDetails into three properties, to have five in total. Then use a horizontal StackPanel in your ItemTemplate to show three TextBlocks for the houseDetails. Or a single TextBlock with three Runs. In order to show text, you should generally be using TextBlock instead of Label.

Comment: the colors are not fixed for first,second or third index. They too change based on a logic.

Comment: Then add three more properties for the colors.

Comment: And how do i bind foreground color?

Comment: Does color property has to be string or color type?

Comment: Foreground is a System.Windows.Media.Brush. The view model property is usually a System.Windows.Media.Color. A SolidColorBrush in the view would have its Color property bound to the view model property. There are hundreds of examples on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, first you need to separate the  `houseDetails` property into 3 strings, something similar to this:

```
public class selectedLevel
{
   public string Level { get; set; }

   public string PlanetSelected { get; set; }

   public string houseDetails1 { get; set; }
   public string houseDetails2 { get; set; }
   public string houseDetails3 { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use a `TextBlock` wrapped by a `Border` instead of the third `Label` and use [Runs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.run?view=net-5.0) inside it to pick a different color for each one and bind them to the corresponding properties:

```
<Border HorizontalAlignment="Center" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
    <TextBlock x:Name="LevelDetails" Grid.Row="2" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold">
        <Run Text="{Binding houseDetails1}" Foreground="Red"/>,
        <Run Text="{Binding houseDetails2}" Foreground="Green"/>,
        <Run Text="{Binding houseDetails3}" Foreground="Blue"/>
    </TextBlock>
</Border>
```

And then in the view model:

```
selectedLevels.Add(new selectedLevel
{
    Level = "Mahadasha",
    PlanetSelected = Mahadashas[0].rulerName,
    houseDetails1 =  indicesList[0],
    houseDetails2 =  indicesList[1],
    houseDetails3 =  indicesList[2]                   
});
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is it has fixed colors. I want colors to be set dynamically based on a logic.

Comment: Add properties in the view model for each color and then bind them, if you don't want to use a `SolidColorBrush` in your view model you can make a value converter to return colors based on values provided by the properties. It requires a bit of research to understand but luckily it's simple to solve.